# How can I fix Gambas3?

Tags: programming

I am a v.b programmer. I installed Gambas3 on Ubuntu 13.04. The problem is when I create a new project and put the objects on the form then run the project  no objects visible on the form. Note: the folder which I put project on is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Following the steps bellow i had no problem to create, run and view the created user interface:

- Create a new project and select "Graphical application" and press next

[image]

- Select a parent directory for the project and press next

[image]

- Input in the fields "Project name" and "Project title" the desired values and press OK

[image]

- The project window will open and at the left column the project layout will be shown. Double click the FMain file to open in the editor.

[image]

- Drag and drop a label and a button into the form from the available components shown at the right column of the IDE

[image]

- Select one control at a time and input some string at their **text** field property (Just like at Visual Studio)
- Double click the button and the source editor will open, at the respective event handler provide some action, in mine i opted to change label's text property on click:

```vb
Public Sub Button1_Click()

    Label1.Text = "You pressed the button, good!"

End
```

- Click the green play button ("Run") and the form will show up

[image]

- Here is the result of pressing the button

[image]

Comment: @user185789 If the answer has helped to solve your problem, consider accepting it as correct. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) how to do it.